# Would like to have some input on the logomark that I'm currently working on

Tags: logo

everyone. I've been learning logo design and decided to get a brief off of the internet and try my hand at it. This is for a clothing company that wants to create a men's wear line. They want to create stylish but comfortable clothes that people can wear when they are out running errands, spending times with their kids or doing chores around the house. The brand is called Hafun (I changed the name).

I used the letter h and the shape of a persons legs when they are walking to create the logo and used a san serif font to keep the vibe casual. I'm worried that the logomark doesn't quite show what I want it to show or that it might be showing something completely different or unintended. Love to know your input.

[image]

**Edited After input**

[image]

Comment: See https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/682#682 for guidelines on critique questions.

Comment: Having said that, my main issue is you have the trousers walking left, yet we're reading left to right. This makes it look like the guy went to the 'target' & we see him on his way back… Did he like it? Why is he leaving? Flipped image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvYhv.jpg

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. First thought is that the text has too much kerning. Perhaps dial it back a little. Also, I feel the curves need tweaked a little perhaps, especially the left curve of the longest stroke. It doesn't quite match the curve on the right hand side. It's a bit disconcerting.

Comment: @Tetsujin Hi, thank you. I used the symbol in that direction so that it might resemble the lowercase h,  but I see what you mean. It does feel like he's going back. Thanks alot for you input! I'll continue to work on this.

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi! You're right, I didn't really notice the kerning until you mentioned it. It is too much. Regarding the stroke, you mean it seems like it's bulging out a bit too much, right? I'll work on it some more. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it's bulging on the right.  Maybe instead of trying to make shapes with curves, start with a curved path and a thick stroke. At least that way, the thickness will be consistent.

Comment: [see example](https://imgur.com/qBdml20) of what I mean

Comment: @BillyKerr - tbh, the bulge didn't bother me, though I did notice it. I felt it gave it a bit of a 'casual, relaxed-fit pants' vibe… even if it was leaving the scene :)

Comment: @Tetsujin - sure I can see that too, certainly an equally valid opinion. However the bulge is so slight it almost looks like a mistake. If the bulge is deliberate, another option might be to accentuate to make it look even more deliberate.

Comment: I almost got a 'Popeye' 30's feel from it - that bendy-leg cartoon walk - though maybe now I'm over-thinking it ;)

Comment: To be honest, I think the right "walking" pants works in the existing direction -- creates a good flow for the eye, leading you back to the left after reading the type. I also like the slightly deformed shapes of the "pants". My only real criticism would be how uninteresting the type is - just a standard font with some letter spacing.

Comment: I tend to agree with @Tetsujin- the "walking" in the opposite direction makes more sense to me- as well, it more resembles an h which follows with the brand name. I also agree the font could be better/ different- https://imgur.com/a/unUXac3

Comment: @Kyle, haha that walk is a bit too sneaky isn't it? I like the original (or the flipped one) better because it's a more casual walk. You can almost see the person has their hands in the pockets. As others mentioned, the font could be more playful. Perhaps not rule out a serif font or at least something more curvy without trying it out first.

Comment: After reading your inputs, I decided flip the walking direction as suggested by @Tetsujin and gave up on the idea of having it resemble the lowercase h. It started to feel like I was forcing the shape.

Comment: I decided to keep the bulging shape, but exaggerated it more, 
or rather made it look more intentional as you suggested @BillyKerr .

Comment: Yeah, it never did look like an `h` to me, more like two thirds of a `k`

Comment: @Scott I played around with the fonts and settled on one sans serif font and a serif font. I updated the question with the new version. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Just my personal choice... but picking a different, canned and ready, font as not what I meant. In my world a *logo* should really never merely be a typeface *anyone* can choose from a font menu.

Comment: @Scott, noted. I think I have a lot to learn about fonts and creating them, specially when it comes to logos. My design eye isn't as good as it should be, I'll keep working on it and see what I can come up with :)